# Need a PowerShell website report to re-try authentication-enabled websites a second time after the initial HTTP 401

Tags: powershell, loops, web, http-headers, powershell-3.0

I utilize a 51-line PowerShell script below working great when web sites use anonymous authentication but gives false result when they require authentication, even on single sign-on sites letting you right in, because the script logs the **first** HTTP 401 rather than re-trying a second time and logging the HTTP 200 result, because it simply moves on to next site in the list.  Since every authentication-enabled web site always sends HTTP 401 first, I need the script to pause one second giving the client time to automatically grab credentials from the directory server and pass them back to the web site which will give an HTTP 200 and report out only the HTTP 200 result, and not the HTTP 401 result of the first try.  Since my script below already has loop logic cycling through a URL list with the "foreach" command, I do not know how to do a nested loop re-trying the HTTP 401-responding sites a second time in order to try to get the HTTP correct 200 result to accurately represent the outcome of what actually happens when internal people access the single sign-on enabled sites.

```
## The URI list to test
$URLListFile = "C:\URLList.txt" 
$URLList = Get-Content $URLListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
  $Result = @()

  Foreach($Uri in $URLList) {
  $time = try{
  $request = $null
   ## Request the URI, and measure how long the response took.
  $result1 = Measure-Command { $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $uri }
  $result1.TotalMilliseconds
  } 
  catch
  {
   <# If the request generated an exception (i.e.: 500 server
   error or 404 not found), we can pull the status code from the
   Exception.Response property #>
   $request = $_.Exception.Response
   $time = -1
  }  
  $result += [PSCustomObject] @{
  Time = Get-Date;
  Uri = $uri;
  StatusCode = [int] $request.StatusCode;
  StatusDescription = $request.StatusDescription;
  ResponseLength = $request.RawContentLength;
  TimeTaken =  $time; 
  }

}
    #Prepare email body in HTML format
if($result -ne $null)
{
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE>Website Availability Report</TITLE><BODY background-color:peachpuff><font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""><H2> Website Availability Report </H2></font><Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0><TR bgcolor=gray align=center><TD><B>URL</B></TD><TD><B>StatusCode</B></TD><TD><B>StatusDescription</B></TD><TD><B>ResponseLength</B></TD><TD><B>TimeTaken</B></TD</TR>"
    Foreach($Entry in $Result)
    {
        if($Entry.StatusCode -ne "200")
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"
        }
        else
        {
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"
        }
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.uri)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusCode)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.StatusDescription)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.ResponseLength)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.timetaken)</TD></TR>"
    }
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"
}

$Outputreport | out-file C:\Scripts\Test.htm
Invoke-Expression C:\Scripts\Test.htm
```

Comment: Hello!, Did you try "Start-Sleep" command?

Comment: @RodolfoC.Méndez - I am not sure where in my code I would insert the  "Start-Sleep" command.